# How can I Cache Results in a 2d Dynamic Programming Question?

Tags: javascript, recursion, time-complexity, dynamic-programming

I am working on the leetcode question, Trapping Rainwater II, `https://leetcode.com/problems/trapping-rain-water-ii/`.

Given an m x n integer matrix heightMap representing the height of each unit cell in a 2D elevation map, return the volume of water it can trap after raining.

My current solution is to use dynamic programming. I am aware there are more efficient solutions such as a priority queue, but I am keen on getting this to work, for learning purposes.

The crux of my algorithm is that for any given cell, I need to determine the bottleneck wall where water can eventually spill out from. This is the objective of my `dp` function.

My solution relies on recursing a dp function on all the adjacent cells, recursing those, and so on, until we hit the border of the matrix which is the terminal case.

Consider this elevation matrix:

```
[4, 1, 4],
[1, 2, 1],
[4, 2, 4],
[4, 4, 4]
```

Here, say I want to figure out how much water I can trap at the cell row=1,col=1, which has a height of 2. To do so, I call my dp function on all of its neighbors. Three of its neighbors are borders, which are terminal cases. They immediately send back their cell heights (which are all 1), and end their recursive chains. The south neighbor however needs further recursive calls.

When I recurse down to the bottom 2, that cell calls its south, west, and east borders, which all return 4. Then, the bottom 2 cell itself returns 4 back to the parent 2, and the recursion completes. The implication is that the bottom 2 has a minimum boundary of 4. In practice it doesn't, because it's north border is also a 2, but I don't consider that cell anymore because it has already been visited in the chain.

However, that means if I try to cache the result for calling the bottom 2, I would cache the result as 4. But that isn't accurate. If I need to recurse to the bottom 2 in the future, as part of a different chain, I may need to consider its north neighbor, if I haven't visited it already.

So I'm not really sure how I can add any caching to this and avoid time-limit exceeded problems.

If instead of ignoring the north 2, I still recurse on that, I would face an infinite recursion problem.

I also tried only caching the absolute top-level results. So in the above example, I would only cache the result for row=1,col=1 after that full recursive chain runs. This speeds up the time a lot, but it is still TLE for larger matrices. Am I overlooking a way to add caching or improve the speed of my method? I've seen other people use DFS so I believe it should be possible.

My current code with top-level only caching:

```
var trapRainWater = function(heightMap) {
    const cache = {}; // maps dp calls to their outputs

    // the goal of the DP function is to find the constraint barrier for a given cell
    function dp(rowCoordinate, colCoordinate, visitedCells, depth) {
        // caching
        const cacheKey = JSON.stringify([rowCoordinate, colCoordinate]);
        if (cacheKey in cache) {
            return cache[cacheKey]; 
        }
        
        // create a copy of the set in memory to avoid pass-by-reference
        const visitedCellsNew = new Set(visitedCells);

        const cellHeight = heightMap[rowCoordinate][colCoordinate];

        // if we are at a boundary of the matrix, we will spill over the edge, immediately return the cells height as the boundary
        if (rowCoordinate === 0 || rowCoordinate === heightMap.length - 1 || colCoordinate === 0 || colCoordinate === heightMap[0].length - 1) {
            cache[cacheKey] = cellHeight;
            return cellHeight;
        }

        // neighbors to call, we are no longer at a boundary at this point in the code
        const neighborCoords = [
            [rowCoordinate - 1, colCoordinate], // top
            [rowCoordinate, colCoordinate + 1], // right
            [rowCoordinate, colCoordinate - 1], // left
            [rowCoordinate + 1, colCoordinate], // bottom
        ];

        // remove visited cells in the current DP chain
        neighborCoordsFiltered = neighborCoords.filter(coords => !visitedCellsNew.has(JSON.stringify(coords)));

        // add current cell to visited for future calls
        visitedCellsNew.add(JSON.stringify([rowCoordinate, colCoordinate]));

        // recurse on neighbors
        const recursedDps = neighborCoordsFiltered.map(coords => dp(coords[0], coords[1], visitedCellsNew, depth + 1));
        const minRecursedDps = Math.min(...recursedDps);
        const result = Math.max(cellHeight, minRecursedDps);

        // cache the result if this is a top-level call
        if (depth === 0) {
            cache[cacheKey] = result;
        }
        return result;
    }


    // creative matrix of the boundaries
    const restrictiveBoundaries = new Array(heightMap.length).fill().map(() => new Array(heightMap[0].length));
    // calculate the spillage points that can be reached from every cell
    for (let rowNumber = 0; rowNumber < heightMap.length; rowNumber++) {
        for (let colNumber = 0; colNumber < heightMap[0].length; colNumber++) {
            restrictiveBoundaries[rowNumber][colNumber] = dp(rowNumber, colNumber, new Set(), 0);
        }
    }

    // calculate the total water
    let totalWater = 0;
    for (let rowNumber = 0; rowNumber < heightMap.length; rowNumber++) {
        for (let colNumber = 0; colNumber < heightMap[0].length; colNumber++) {
            const cellHeight = heightMap[rowNumber][colNumber];
            const restrictiveBoundary = restrictiveBoundaries[rowNumber][colNumber];
            if (cellHeight < restrictiveBoundary) {
                totalWater += restrictiveBoundary - cellHeight;
            }
        }
    }
    return totalWater;
}
```